# Notificação pelo Browser

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Olá meu nome é André Neto, eu estou desenvolvendo um software, e dentro dele existe uma central de emails, onde o usuário pode enviar um email de dentro do sistema e eu guardo esses dados de envio.
Agora o problema, preciso notificar a pessoa que recebeu o email, (obs: ela esta cadastrada no meu sistema pelo seu email), via uma notificação do browser, assim como o facebook faz com as notificações, e gostaria de fazer essa notificação mesmo que a pessoa não esteja logada no meu sistema, o servidor iria enviar essa mensagem.
Qualquer idéia de como posso fazer isso, é muito aceita!
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Já fizeste alguma coisa? Que linguagem tens no servidor e qual a parte que já funciona?

Comment: Fiz a aplicação de envio de email, ele envia o email e salva as informações no banco de dados, e o email é enviado.

Comment: que tecnologia você usa no servidor? mas posso adiantar que o ideal é com o uso da [`Notification API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/notificacoes) no Cliente e `Web Sockets` no Servidor. Para `ASP.NET` tem o [`SignalR`](https://www.asp.net/signalr), para `Node.JS` tem o [Socket.IO](http://socket.io), `PHP` o [`Ratchet`](http://socketo.me) e `Java` [`SockJS`](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)

Comment: Acho que me expressei errado, gostaria de notificar outro usuário logado no sistema, se ele receber um email de dentro do meu sistema através de outro usuário.

Comment: @AndreNeto esta é a idea central das ferramentas acima

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada no SockJS, pois é a linguagem que mais domino.